# how to know yoast seo image is uploaded or not and add conditions for og:image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, share, yoast

In WordPress for social sharing I am using yoast seo plugin.Now as per client requirement I need to put conditions for og:image as follows.

1. if image is added in yoast meta box for post/page, show that image
2. if there is no image in yoast seo, check for featured image in post/page
3. if there is no image in yoast seo and featured image show some image from setting.
   How am I to know if image is uploaded in yoast meta box or not for specific page and fulfill the above requirement?
   I tried the following but it only replaces the image from yoast meta box.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_image', 'ag_yoast_seo_fb_share_images', 10, 1 );

function ag_yoast_seo_fb_share_images( $img ) {

    return ( $img && ! empty( $img ) ) ?  $img : get_field( 'social_share_image', 'options' );
};
```

Comment: I did not tested real senario. But hopfully it will work for you. So you can check by following code:


add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_image', 'ag_yoast_seo_fb_share_images', 10, 1 );

function ag_yoast_seo_fb_share_images( $img ) {
global $post;
if( $img && ! empty( $img ) ) {
return $img;
} else if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full');

if (empty($image)) {
 return get_field( 'social_share_image', 'options' );
}
else {
 return $image;
}
} else {
return get_field( 'social_share_image', 'options' );
}
};

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
    function insert_fb_in_head() {
        global $post;
        if( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
            $default_image = get_field( 'social_share_image', 'options' ); //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
        } else{
            $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
        }
    }
```